# Fancy header alignment

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, alignment

This is the header of my two-side document. 
[image]
As you can see when the number increases the vertical line that separates the pagenumber from the chapter name is shifted a bit inward. I would like to have the position of this line fixed and aligned with the text box of the page.
This is my code:

```
\documentclass [11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\geometry{
inner=2.4cm, % Inner margin
outer=4cm, % Outer margin
top=3.5cm, % Top margin
bottom=3cm, % Bottom margin
heightrounded,
bindingoffset=4mm,
showframe,
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage\hspace{7pt}\textcolor{gray}{|}\hspace{5pt}\nouppercase{\textcolor{gray}{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\textcolor{gray}{\rightmark}}\hspace{5pt}\textcolor{gray}{|}\hspace{7pt}\thepage}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the picture: the page numbers are flush with the left margin (on even numbered pages).

Comment: @egreg try now, I added the geometry part

Comment: The same. You're missing `headheight=13.6pt`, by the way. You *must* have some `fancyhdr` command to offset the page number.

Comment: @egreg I don't have `headheight=13.6pt` in my code and the pagenumber offest is obtained with the `bindingoffset=4mm`

Comment: You *should* have `headheight=13.6pt` (look in the log file to know why). The offset of the page numbers *can't* be obtained with `bindingoffset`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to offset the page number in the margin, you need to use `\fancyhfoffset`. Enclose the page number in a box as wide as the offset (and big enough to contain the widest Roman page number).

```
\documentclass [11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\geometry{
  inner=2.4cm, % Inner margin
  outer=4cm, % Outer margin
  top=3.5cm, % Top margin
  bottom=3cm, % Bottom margin
  headheight=13.6pt,
  heightrounded,
  bindingoffset=4mm,
  showframe,
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhfoffset[LE]{20pt}
\fancyhfoffset[RO]{20pt}
\fancyhead[LE]{%
  \makebox[20pt][l]{\thepage}%
  {\color{gray}\makebox[0pt]{\textbar}\hspace{5pt}\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
}
\fancyhead[RO]{%
  {\color{gray}\nouppercase{\rightmark}\hspace{5pt}\makebox[0pt]{\textbar}}%
  \makebox[20pt][r]{\thepage}%
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Abstract}

\kant[1-40]

\end{document}
```

I also set the bar in a zero width box.

[image]